# Magento main content blocks. Removing wrapping <p> tags

Tags: magento

I'm doing maintenance work on a magento site for a client and I'm trying to w3c validate the site.

The problem is that the blocks in the main column are all being wrapped with a `<p>` tag.

```
<div class="col-main last">
    <div class="std">
        <p>
            <div class="flexslider">
            ...
```

I tried using debug_backtrace and managed to locate the problem to originate somewhere between calls to the Abstract class (`app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php`). Maybe there is some sort of filter that applies the `<p>` tag?
I've not previously worked with magento so any help towards debugging the issue would be greatly appreciated.

Where should I start looking?

Comment: Does this happen for all pages or only CMS pages? If it's only for cms pages then the `<p>` comes from the content of the page. Edit the page in `CMS->Pages` and replace the tag with a `<div>`.

Comment: You're spot on @Marius . If you post an answer I'll accept it =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's only for cms pages then the `<p>` comes from the content of the page. Edit the page in `CMS->Pages` and replace the tag with a `<div>`.